# Is it possible to output a variable as a cmd command from a c++ program

Tags: c++, cmd

Im making a simple command line program just to get my C++ knowledge to a basic level, 
I would like to send a command from the C++ program to CMD that is made up of part of a command and the rest a variable here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string directory;
    cout<<"Input the directory you would like to make your folder in: ";
    cin>> directory;
    system("mkdir" directory);
}
```

I get the error:

```
error: expected ')' before 'directory'|
```

Does anyone know a way of doing this? In the end I would like CMD to execute the command "mkdir C:*Inputted Directory*

I have hacked around with it trying to work it out, but to no success, I also have had a look on the internet but to no avail, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Borgleader: you are missing the point that `system` does not support more than a single argument. OP just needs to get his String together.

Comment: Why not just use C library or boost functions instead of dealing with shell commands?

Comment: @Borgleader: Ermm!?!

Comment: @Jongware My bad, I never use system, but if it had been using more than a single argument, a comma would have been necessary. Comment removed.

Comment: As I said, @crasmastr I am only just learning c++, so I dont know all the options, would it be possible to explain how I could use what you just outlined?

Comment: [std::system](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/system)

Comment: Add a `+` between `"mkdir"` and `directory`. And a space after `"mkdir"`: `"mkdir "`.

Comment: Even if you fix your `system` problem you still won't be able to compile due to the fact you forgot to include `<string>`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than call out to the shell use the `_mkdir` (for [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2fkk4dzw.aspx)) or `mkdir` (for [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir)) function instead:

```
_mkdir(directory.c_str());
```

For Windows you'll need `#include <direct.h>`, for Linux you'll need `#include <sys/stat.h>` and `#include <sys/types.h>`

Comment: I'm now getting the error "error: 'mkdir' was not declared in this scope" how would I declare this?

Comment: @EuanWilliams - I've added more info to the answer

Comment: Alternatively, `boost::filesystem::create_directory( )` which hides those Linux/Windows differences.

Comment: @MSalters It is asking me to declare boost? Sorry I am very new to C++